# Values from ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode() and web3.eth.abi.decodeLog() are different than expected

Tags: events, logs

After submitting a transaction. I'd like to get information from the event generated.

```
event GameCreated(uint256 gameId, uint256 wager, address Player1);
```

We tried this with both Ethers Library and Web3.
**ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode()**
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder
**web3.eth.abi.decodeLog()**
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#decodelog

```
    const object = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(['uint', 'uint', 'address'], 
    "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000136b8380cec84000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432b4ada5355162f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024cb65b70804a8c9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432a14221b4829ab00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024cc9c6f4011954d",
    )
    console.log(object[0].toNumber())
    console.log(object[1].toString())
    console.log(object[2])
```

Here is a screenshot of the event log from Mumbai Polygon Scan.

[image]

Expected values are:

- gameId: 1
- wager: 1
- Player1: 0xD544F62f52497d84884f17CC923a8BA966A75537

Actual Values returned by both Ethers and Web3 libraries:

- gameId: "514942734672828"
- wager: "4836593396267459283"
- Player1: "0x0000000000000000000025D21dE5f3de05B8346f"

There has to be some sort of conversion that I'm missing.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The object you're trying to decode `0x00..4d` is way different than the one from polygonScan. In particular it has 5 arguments instead of 3. I think you're decoding the wrong thing. To get the logs you have to pick the transaction receipt and look at the `logs` key. Then you have to pick the right log by checking the `topics[0]` value.

Comment: You're absolutely right.
There was an array of 2 logs.

And my brilliant brain chose the wrong one -_____-

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
data="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000136b8380cec84000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432b4ada5355162f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024cb65b70804a8c9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432a14221b4829ab00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024cc9c6f4011954d"
```

decode data should be 5 parameters.

`0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000136b8380cec84 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432b4ada5355162f 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024cb65b70804a8c9 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000432a14221b4829ab 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024cc9c6f4011954d`

So,the data you have given is wrong.